# Run SpringBoot-based docker image return error message:Invalid or corrupt jarfile /app.jar

Tags: docker, spring-boot

I followed the Spring **official tutorial**(https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/) to build springBoot-based app to docker image. The docker image was built successfully, but when I wanted to execute `docker run` command to start a container, I got the following error message:

```
Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile /app.jar
```

and the containner couldn't start running normally.

Has anybody gotten the same error message before? I really need your help. Thank you very much!

Comment: Could you please explain what 'gradlew container" mean? I'm now using spring-boot-maven-plugin and docker-maven-plugin to build jar and docker image.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain clearly. From your error, the jar file is not generated properly. You need review that tutorial to check which step is wrong. No one else can help this.

Comment: But I execute the springBoot-based jar package builded by  spring-boot-maven-plugin using command "java -jar xxx.jar". It works well. Does it illustrate that the jar file is OK?

Answer (score 10):

> Structure of java aplication

```
Demo
└── src
|    ├── main
|    │   ├── java
|    │   │   └── org
|    │   │       └── demo
|    │   │           └── Application.java
|    │   └── resources
|    │       └── application.properties
|    └── test
|         └── java
|               └── org
|                   └── demo
|                         └── Application.java  
├──── Dockerfile
├──── pom.xml
```

> Content of pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.executablejar</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>demo Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <java-version>1.8</java-version>
    <docker.image.prefix>springDemo</docker.image.prefix>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <finalName>demo</finalName>
</build>
```

> Content of Dockerfile

```
FROM java:8
EXPOSE 8080
ADD /target/app.jar demo.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","demo.jar"]
```

> Commands to build and run image

Go to the directory of project.Lets say D:/Demo

```
$ cd D/demo
$ mvn clean install
$ docker build demo .
$ docker run -p 8080:8080 -t demo
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to add the JAR_FILE build arg to the dockerfile-maven-plugin, since it is missing in the code sample provided by the spring tutorial:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
   <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.4.9</version>
   <configuration>
      <repository>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</repository>
      <buildArgs>
         <JAR_FILE>target/${project.build.finalName}.jar</JAR_FILE>
      </buildArgs>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, check the name of jar application  in dockerFile